# How to validate a property of a component entity via hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I have the following class:

```
class Foo
{
   @Valid
   private Bar bar;
}
```

In Bar, I have:

```
class Bar
{
   @NotEmpty
   private String baz;
}
```

I want to validate the property `bar.baz` from foo. But when I try `validateProperty()` and pass the string `bar.baz` as the property name, I get an error that there's no such property. Is it not possible to validate child properties in this way?

Comment: Where is the "child" mentioned in your question title? I don't see the keyword `extends` anywhere. Is this an oddity of hibernate?

Comment: @Rusher Sorry, by child I meant contained within the first class. As `Bar` is contained within `Foo` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Bean Validation specification](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/) the property must be a direct property of the bean you are validating:

> Set> validateProperty(T object, String
>   propertyName, Class... groups) validates a given field or property
>   of an object. An IllegalArgumentException is thrown when
>   validateProperty() is called and object is null or propertyName is
>   null empty or invalid or null is passed to the varargs groups
>   parameter. The property name is the JavaBeans property name (as
>   defined by the JavaBeans Introspector class). This method implements
>   the logic described in Section 4.6, “Validation routine” but only to
>   the given property. @Valid is not honored by this method. This method
>   is useful for partial object validation.

That said, Hibernate Validator supports property paths as you can also see [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/test/java/org/hibernate/validator/test/internal/engine/ValidatorTest.java#L81). To help any further, you would need to post the full stack trace.